# check if space is before and after a string, to remove the string

Tags: python

I am analyzin lycris and want to remove such words like "la la la", "na na na", etc.

I want to do that with a list of words and then with the re.sub function. But this also removes eh "na" from words, which starts with na. How can I just remove the strings, which has "na na na na na na na" and "ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah"

```
lyrics = "say my name say my name drei zwei eins null baby make it rain baby ruf honigtopf tropft bleibe ganze nacht lang online yeah screenshots kopf na na na na na na na baby ruf honigtopf tropft bleibe ganze nacht lang online yeah screenshots kopf na na na na na na na ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah"

stopwords = [' na ', ' ah', '-ah', 'yeah']

lyrics = re.sub(r'|'.join(map(re.escape, stopwords )), '', lyrics)
```

Comment: Is that mandatory to use `re` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simply try to use a `for` loop:

```
lyrics = "say my name say my name drei zwei eins null baby make it rain baby ruf honigtopf tropft bleibe ganze nacht lang online yeah screenshots kopf na na na na na na na baby ruf honigtopf tropft bleibe ganze nacht lang online yeah screenshots kopf na na na na na na na ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah"

stopwords = ['na ', ' ah', '-ah', 'yeah'] # updated as comments since you provided wrong list

for word in stopwords:
    lyrics = lyrics.replace(word, '') # replaces every word with empty string
lyrics = lyrics.replace('  ', ' ') # removes double spaces if needed
print(lyrics)
```

Comment: I tried already this one, the problem is, some "na" and "ah" will not be deleted. 
The solutions of this approach is:
`say my name say my name drei zwei eins null baby make it rain baby ruf honigtopf tropft bleibe ganze nacht lang online screenshots kopfnananababy ruf honigtopf tropft bleibe ganze nacht lang online screenshots kopfnananaah`

Comment: What do you mean. I also get the same output? `say my name say my name drei zwei eins null baby make it rain baby ruf honigtopf tropft bleibe ganze nacht lang online screenshots kopfnananababy ruf honigtopf tropft bleibe ganze nacht lang online screenshots kopfnananaah`. I see all your `stopwords` value removed.

Comment: WHere do you see `na` and `ah`?

Comment: here in the end `kopfnananababy`, `kopfnananaah`. If you compare it with the start string, there you can see, some spaces got deleted and merged some `na` and `ah` together.

Comment: Well, that's a problem with your input list not the code. Change the `' na '` to `'na '` so that it works.

Comment: Great to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
lyrics = "say my name say my name drei zwei eins null baby make it rain baby ruf honigtopf tropft bleibe ganze nacht lang online yeah screenshots kopf na na na na na na na baby ruf honigtopf tropft bleibe ganze nacht lang online yeah screenshots kopf na na na na na na na ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah ah-ah-ah"

stopwords = [' na ', ' ah', '-ah', 'yeah']
for i in stopwords:
    lyrics.replace(i, '')
```

Comment: What about double spaces. When you run the code at some places there's a double space for no reason.